# Coil current discharge on a resistor in a simple circuit

Tags: ltspice

Attached is a picture with the circuit in  LTspice.

There is a 5 volt pulse voltage source.  Parallel to the voltage source I connected a coil and a resistor.

Why don't I see the high voltage on the resistor when the coil discharges itself?

[image: The picture shows the voltage on the resistor]

The picture shows the voltage on the resistor.

Comment: As generators have generally 50 Ohm internally, you should "see" what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You should see it ...
If you test your circuit with a "real" generator and ... its internal 50 Ohm impedance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> *The question is: why don't I see the high voltage on the resistor when
> the coil discharges itself?*

The dominant component in your circuit is the voltage source; it delivers the voltage you see irrespective of L1 and R1. In fact L1 and R1 can be removed from the circuit and the voltage will be the same. The pulse dominates and the energy stored in L1 is not allowed to produce an effect.

Maybe try putting the resistor in series with the inductor to see the flyback voltage. Or, use a diode in the feed to L1 from the pulse but, be aware that the current produced over 2 seconds in your present circuit will be 20,000 amps so, maybe consider lowering the pulse width by 10,000.